# soap:address and http:address

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I have some problems with understanding the difference between **soap:address** and **http:address** tags in wsdl. Is it interchangeble? Can I use **soap:address** instead of **http:address**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

No, You can't. They are not interchangeable. They belong to different WSDL Bindings.

**Long answer**

The WSDL format is not bound to a particular protocol. On the contrary, it can be extended to be used in conjunction with various protocols such as SOAP, HTTP and MIME. This kind of extensions is called Binding. A Binding defines the protocol and the message format used for communicating with a web service. Each Binding has a namespace and associated namespace prefix prepended to tags. The namespace prefixes and the tags are separated with a colon. So, the **soap** namespace prefix in the **soap:address** tag indicates that it belongs to the SOAP Binding and the **http** namespace prefix in the **http:address** tag indicates that it belongs to the HTTP Binding. You CAN'T mix them in a Binding, because according to the WSDL Specification a Binding MUST specify exactly one protocol. But You can have different Bindings for one portType.

**Links**

1. [WSDL 1.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl)
2. [WSDL 1.2 Specification: Bindings](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-wsdl12-bindings-20020709/)